Any way to schedule many individual jobs to run at a later datetime from apex without?
I like to be able to write Apex code to perform reminder work.  It would be when something is created, somewho queue a class/method to run at a later time.  It would only once.  But there can be many individual instances.  So, more than 100 instances could be queued.  I believe the limit on scheduled Apex is 100 jobs.  So I don't see how scheduled Apex could do it.
Anyone know if any facility that could be used where Apex can say run this class and method and such and such a date and time and have a very large number of instances, could be thousands?
we did try a flow but run into some sort of restriction is what is allowed in a time-dependent step.

The issue we had with flow is we wanted to use "Every time a record is updated and meets the condition requirements". and that doesn't allow scheduled paths.

why not have a batchable that reschedules (+5 minutes)  itself after finishing?  The batchable queries the records that need the reminder work.  One scheduled job  and reminders with just a few minutes of latency

I thought about that but that ends up being many executions per day.  If it were in an org where we were the owner and controlling the operation of all processes I could go that way.  But this could be installed in other orgs and we want to minimize impact.
But I haven't ruled that idea out.  If we did go that way, we'd probably make the interval tunable.

Have you checked "Record Trigger Flow" and added a "Scheduled Paths" to it?

the impact on the org from a job running every 5 minutes (1440/5) = 288 times with a database query that if indexed should run quickly (since you can probably filter by LastModifiedDate) doesn't sound very intensive and it will do the same work as individual record-triggered flows

I did try a record trigger flow with a scheduled path.  The issue is that it won't run when the start condition is "Only when a record is updated to meet the condition requirements" and the scheduled path won't run with "Every time a record is updated and meets the condition requirements" selected.  See https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/2021/03/schedule-your-path-in-salesforce-flow
However I did some playing and think I can trick the condition in a formula so the "Only when a record is updated to meet the condition requirements" will always fire

What we have done in many client's places is create a Bg_Task__c object with Delay_Until__c field which tells when that task needs to run. Then have a job/flow/external scheduler that wakes up every minute and checks mature tasks and runs them.
